# How to set as a background to all rows in listview?

Tags: android, listview, background, android-linearlayout, adapter

In my application, I have to create a list view and each item/row should have same background.
I have referred this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-background-row-style-rounded-corner-alternate-color.html and this http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90 
tutorial.
In this they have created an array having different Images and setting them as a row background.
but I have to set only one Image as a row or listitem background..
So is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you wanna set one backgroud image to listView or foreach row small backgroud image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the layout background color in

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner); // change your layout background in your adapter.
```

Comment: v is a View object, View v.

Answer (score 1):

go to "row" or the "list item" xml file in layout folder and set attribute to parent view  **android:background="@drawable/yourBackgroudImage"**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/yourBackgroudImage"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Comment: It's always a recommended method, the things that can be set in the xml layout should be done so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create the following file in the **drawable** folder as follows:

*list_selecter.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

If you would like the background color to change, you need to add these two files too. Please note the hex values in the `startColor`, `centerColor` and `endColor` nodes. The hex value there can be changed to any value you feel appropriate for your application:

*gradient_bg.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#f1f1f2"
    android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
    android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
    android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

*gradient_bg_hover.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
<!-- Gradient BgColor for listrow Selected -->
<gradient
  android:startColor="#A6A6A6"
  android:centerColor="#757575"
  android:endColor="#4A4A4A"
  android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Then in the actual xml file in the **layout** folder, you need to add the following line to the LinearLayout:

```
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Comment: I know it is From AndroidHive.info
But what if I want to have only Image as a background...

Comment: then all you need to do is the following:     `android:background="@drawable/background"` to the LinearLayout node in the layout xml file. Background is an actual png file saved in your drawable folder.